# ADF pagination rule to get total row count from rest API and add as end condition

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rest-api

I have created a restAPI connection with base url:[https://heineken-dev.collibra.com/rest/2.0/assets?offset={offset}](https://heineken-dev.collibra.com/rest/2.0/assets?offset=%7Boffset%7D)

and in copy Data activity source pagination rules , I have added as below.
[image: paginationRule]

but in the restAPI result set: total: 14518 which is the total number of records.
I want to get this total 14518 into end condition of offset.Can someone help me do that.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> ADF pagination rule to get total row count from rest API and add as end condition.

**As per you requirement in the rest API result set you are getting `total: 14518` which is the total number of records.** And you want to use this in the end condition.

**To achieve this:**

> here I am using this [sample Rest Api](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2)

- First you need to get the result set of api from web activity.
  [image]
  **Result set:** here you will get that `total: 14518`
  [image]
- Now in copy activity set the pagination rule as below:
  set Renge as `1::1000` so it will loop the url infinite time on the offset of 1000 and the set the end condition as `MaxRequestNumber : @string(activity('Web1').output.total_pages)` so it will end the looping when it reaches the max request number.
  [image]

**UPDATE**

updating answer for other community members. Agreed with @Sukanya by adding `$.total` the value of total will be taken from the rest API's response in the end condition as below:

[image]

Comment: I could solve this issue by adding $.total in the end condition(in range) which will take the total from rest API. Hope this helps someone in future.