# How to use API offset pagination in Azure COPY ACTIVITY to dynamically stop when the last page has been processed

Tags: rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm working on a data integration pipeline in Azure Data Factory, and I need to implement offset pagination for a copy activity. I have an API that returns a response with pagination information, and I want to use that information to perform offset pagination in the copy activity.

Here's an example of the API response:

```
{
    "log_id": "3133A719-AB38-4846-1111-9D37AD9D682F",
    "pagination": {
        "next_page": 2,
        "last_page": 2428,
        "total_records": 24274,
        "prev_page": 1,
        "current_page": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "ws_fin_out_header": [
            {
                "serial": "TST1400002"
            },
            {
                "serial": "TST1400001"
            }
        ]
    },
    "auth": true,
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "uuid": "E0EB1293-1111-4505-A02D-950A6477CF53",
    "version": "4",
    "sqlResult": null,
    "token_succes": true,
    "benchmark": "request finished in 219 ms",
    "token": false
}
```

I use QueryParameters {pageNumber} = Range(1, 2428,1) but the 2428 is now hardcoded.
How do dynamically set the end of the range so that the copy activity stops when all is processed.

I already tried to work with "EndCondition": $.data.ws_fin_out_header = EMPTY. This did not work.

Any ideas how to set the offSet correctly and stop when done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your scenario, you can directly pass the value to end condition and stop pagination in range as below:

In your condition it can be like `$pagination.total_records`

[image]

Also, you can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042047/adf-pagination-rule-to-get-total-row-count-from-rest-api-and-add-as-end-conditio/76051673#76051673).

Comment: Thank you. This works fine as long as the API returns data.
But the Copy Activity fails when there is no data returned:

    "data": {
        "ws_fin_out_header": []
How do I cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Information, I tried it and got error. I have have a total of 38,967 records, and you've set the 'end' expression to **$.metadata.total**. However, I'm encountering an issue where it's attempting to access the 40th page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuFFM.png)

Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 404 NotFound, please check your activity settings.
Request URL: https://extapi.winnowsolutions.com/pulldelivery/transactions-datasets/50253/result/?page=40.
Response: {"errors":[{"key":"INVALID_DATASET_URL","message":"Invalid dataset url or page number!","source":"command result payloadUrl"}]},Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: Don't post this as answer to this question. If you are facing error, ask as a new question in this platform rather than posting this as answer.